# Transform option for Word Art

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, transform

I don't see the transform option anywhere. I am using Microsoft Word 2013.   Unfortunately, I cannot upload a picture because I don't have enough reputation points.

When I go to drawing tools > format > shape effects > the last option on the bottom is 3D rotation, not transform.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: *tools, not toos

Comment: Do you have a WordArt object selected?

Comment: @NedCui if you upload the image to Imgur and add the link a user with higher rep will be able to embed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

#### When I go to drawing tools > format > shape effects > the last option is 3D rotation.

You are looking the wrong place. To find the "transform" option:

Tools → Format → **Text Effects** → Transform

---

#### Change the shape of WordArt

> After you insert WordArt, you can change the shape of it by using the formatting choices on the Drawing Tools tab.
>
> 1. Click the WordArt you want to change.
>
>    [image: Selected WordArt]
> 2. When you do that, the Drawing Tools Format tab will appear.
> 3. On the Drawing Tools Format tab, click Text Effects >Transform and select the effect you want.
>
>    [image]
>
> Important: The Text Effects Shape Effects [image: menu button menu].
>   If you don't see Transform at the bottom of the menu, make sure you've
>   clicked the Text Effects menu.

Source [Change the shape of WordArt](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-shape-of-WordArt-58df52bd-3925-492b-8ab3-78ba53b46d0f)